# Is there a good Text-to-Speech (TTS) solution for python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

Does someone know a good speech synthesizer for Python 3 on Linux?

I tried the espeak bindings but they are only for Python 2.6/2.7...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common one I've seen is pyTTS, which stands for Python Text to Speech (no surprise there). You can get it from [pyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyTTS).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I look for an application which runs on Linux